# how can we calculate options profit and loss using volatility and implied volatility in a span margin calculation

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, financial-markets, market-model

[image]

complete the table below, mainly we have to use black-scholes model for implied volatility calculations which I am getting as 43 % but now how to make a gain and loss table using this implied volatility

Comment: In each scenario you will have a Futures price and a Vol, so you compute the option price with black-scholes using those two figures. From the calculated option price you subtract 351.75 to find the gain/loss per option.

Comment: For example in Scenario 1 Futures price will be 10974 (unchanged) and volatility will be X+45 , where X is the current implied vol (X is 43 according to your calculation, which I haven't checked).